# Concatenate strings and store them in a buffer in ANSI C

Tags: c, string, ansi-c

I have a function that calls OutputBuffer serveral times:

```
void display(void)
{
    OutputBuffer("This is String One");
    sprintf(PrintBuffer, "String Two %s",modeStr);
    OutputBuffer(PrintBuffer);
    sprintf(PrintBuffer,"AddString = %s",modeStr2);
    OutputBuffer(PrintBuffer);
}
```

In OutputBuffer i'd like to store the strings in a global variable char TestBuffer[1000] and later on show them on a display:

```
void OutPutBuffer(char *Buffer)
{
    int var = strlen(Buffer);
    sprintf(TestBuffer, Buffer);
}
```

I only get the length of each String but but only the last string (AddString ...). Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: You have to use [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/). OR `snprintf(TestBuffer+strlen(TestBuffer),1000,"%s" Buffer);`

Comment: Beware buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `strcat`

```
void OutputBuffer(char *Buffer)
{
     int var = strlen(Buffer);

     if(var+strlen(TestBuffer)>=1000)
       return;

    strcat(TestBuffer,Buffer);
}
```

Using `snprintf`

```
void OutPutBuffer(char *Buffer)
{
    int var = strlen(Buffer);

     if(var+strlen(TestBuffer)>=1000)
           return;

    snprintf(TestBuffer+strlen(TestBuffer),var,"%s",Buffer);
}
```

Comment: It won't show me the full String, cuts it of exactly after 100 character. Do I have to allocate space seperately or something?

Comment: Nevermind, there was a limit for maximum line size, that i didnt see ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional global variable to save the current position reached on TestBuffer.